# Remove Item from LocalStorage Using Splice

Tags: angular

I am saving a product to localStorage and I need to delete the item from localStorage. I am using

```
deleteItem(i){
localStorage.removeItem(i);
localStorage.setItem(i, JSON.stringify(this.items));
this.items.splice(i,1);
}
```

and I get the argument to the function from

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
<td>
<button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(i)">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

This isn't working. The product is still in localStorage after executing the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - `localStorage.setItem(i, JSON.stringify(this.items));` you're using the item index for the `localStorage` key. It's probably messing things up.

Best way to handle `localStorage` (or any 3rd party source of data) is to create getter & setter functions.

```
getStorageItems(): any[] {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
    } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return [];
    }
}

setStorageItems(items: any[]) {
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

`this.items` refers to the component's scope, which is what you should initialize in component init and derive your view from

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.getStorageItems();
}
```

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <td><button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(i)">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

Finally, in your `deleteItem` component, you should update the **components array** to achieve it's update cycle, and then update the `localStorage`.

```
deleteItem(i) {
    this.items.splice(i, 1);
    this.setStorageItems(this.items);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fingeron. That seems to remove the item from localStorage but I won't know for sure until I'm finished deploying it to the Web.

Comment: I was able to compile the app using "ng serve" with no errors but then when I deployed the app with "ng deploy", the app just didn't work. There are no error messages so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: No errors usually means the code is fine. I don't know what's happening in your deploy process but in a properly built app there shouldn't be a difference between `ng serve` and `ng build`

Answer (score 0):

you must set items to localstorage after changing

```
deleteItem(i){
const newItems=this.items.splice(i,1);
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(newItems));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Milad Ahmadi, but after executing your code, the item is still in localStorage.